# SAP ABAP Append alv row to an other table dynamically?

Tags: abap, alv

[image: This is the picture]

How can I get the selection of the row event?

```
if (alv_table_1_row) is selected or if button is pressed 
append to alv_table_2
```

Can somebody help me? I want at the click of the row to be appended into `alv_table_2` dynamically?

Comment: @Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩 Thanks stack wouldn't allow me to post the pic

Comment: @vwegert I have tried using ok_code to append the row but system gives me dump.I dont know how to get the selection event

Comment: Show us the code, then we might be able to help. No code, you might just get guesswork. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local class like below to handle `double-click` row event of ALV grid.

```
class lcl_alv_event_receiver definition.

  public section.

  methods:  handle_double_click.
    for event double_click of cl_gui_alv_grid
        importing e_row e_column.

endclass.  

class lcl_alv_event_receiver implementation.

    method handle_double_click.
        " Your event handler code here like below
        " read table alv_table_1 index e_row-index into ls_row.
        " append ls_row to alv_table_2.
        " alv_table_2_grid->refresh_table_display( ).
    endmethod.

endclass.
```

Register your event handler somewhere in your code after your left ALV is initialized.

```
 data:  lo_alv_event_receiver  type ref to lcl_event_receiver.
    create object lo_alv_event_receiver.

    set handler lo_alv_event_receiver->handle_double_click for alv_table_1_grid.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "before or after alv declaration"? g

Comment: before First, init your ALV grid, then register the events

Comment: I just approved. What do you mean by "dont exist"? just a method name difference and  you can change to whatever you want.